# Is it possible to use the code \section{\[ \]} without the computer breaking?

Tags: math-mode, sectioning

After doing a mass substitution of a certain heading I had had in my document for `\section{}`, my document stopped compiling. It took me longer than I'd care to admit to figure out what caused it. What it seems to be is that a display `\[ \]` in a section heading makes it too irate to compile. Is there a good way around this?
My way is just to end the `\section{}`, insert the `\[ \]`, and resume with a `\section*{}` afterward, but this seems like it can't be the best way.

Comment: Additionally, the `\section{}` environment also doesn't seem to accept ``\overset{f}{\to}'' or ``\varinjlim''...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\protect` to make `\overset` and `\varinjlim` robust:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{$\protect\overset{f}\to \protect\varinjlim$}
foo
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Display math environments create a new paragraph, and that obviously won't work inside a header. Instead, you can use `$\displaystyle some math$`.

I don't really know why `\varinjlim` doesn't work in sectioning commands. I seems to be defined in some way that breaks the ToC mechanism. Providing an alternative for the table of contents, it compiles, but might not be exactly what you want:

```
\section[$\displaystyle \injlim_k M_k$]{$\displaystyle \varinjlim_k M_k$}
```

(This uses `\injlim` for the toc entry and `\varinjlin` for the actual section.)